# Comparing string to a list in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, compare

I have a list of car models that are in the list as Chevrolet,Ford,BMW, so I enacted this code on them.

cars.getMakes() returns a list with the names mentioned above and they are formatted as such.

cars.getAllModels() returns a similar list with just the car model names.

make is a single string that is either a model name or make name.  Depends on users input.

I want to test to see if what the user put in actually exists in my predetermined lists.
if it does; true.  If not; False.

```
function makeCheck(make) {
    var models = cars.getAllModels();
    var makes = cars.getMakes();
    if (make == makes[make]) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `var make = make;` is not necessary. It is being passed as a parameter.

Comment: I think your make is a number and your makes[make] is a string .. How it will be equal then...??

Comment: What is `makes`? What is `make`?

Comment: @Matt Ball make is not a number I've checked.

Comment: I didn't ask what `make` isn't...

Comment: @MattBall I checked makes[make] and that is undefined that is the issue, but why is it undefined?

Comment: There is a lot of code missing that we need to see.

Comment: I don't understand why you think we can definitively answer the question without knowing what `make` and `makes` are.

Comment: @KirsKringle Because you are trying to use the car's make as an array index. By default, an array's indices in Javascript are [usually] numbers.

Comment: @MattBall Fixed the question to explain more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check that the variable `make` passed to the function is in the list of valid makes:

```
function makeCheck(make) {
    var makes = cars.getMakes();
    return (makes.indexOf(make) != -1);
}
```

Comment: Well then, that was a complete shot in the dark. Glad I guessed correctly.